grub rescue: attempt to read or write outside of partition
I have Ubuntu 20.04 and I want to download Windows 11 or any version at all. I have a USB stick and I firstly resized the sda2, but I guess I did it wrong since when I tried to boot up the computer the next time I always enter grub rescue. I tried ls and here are the results


The can be caused by a corrupted data issue; ie. it contains invalid data thus points to sector/cluster/block beyond the capabilities of what they drive/partition can store.  If you're trying to install windows though; you just boot your windows media & install; you'll be overwriting grub anyway so any grub/file-system errors will get overwritten.
